# XML::Simple is it possible to eliminate tag description?

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I'm trying to parse an xml file using XML::Simple library.
In a designed way a line like:

```
<opt one="1">Text</opt>
```

well be parsed to

```
{ 'one' => 1, 'content' => 'Text' }
```

is it possible to get

```
'opt' => 'Text'
```

instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `NoAttr` option in `XMLin()`:  [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.18/lib/XML/Simple.pm#NoAttr_=%3E_1_#_in+out_-_handy)